# JavaScript Button Handler Patterns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Are there any patterns out that that suggest where to put event handlers in JavaScript?  I can't imagine that they are supposed to be just dumped into the document.Ready.

I don't think that they should go in the MVVM's, as they aren't supposed to talk directly to the view with the exception of data-binding.  That said, I quite often use a button handler to launch a modal popup that directly interacts with a MVVM.  The issue is that sometimes the popup will interact with multiple MVVMs.

I don't want to start a debate / discussion on the topic.  I'm hoping that there is just a concrete answer.

**My Question is... Where do I put the button event handlers?**

Thoughts?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is, where do I put the button event handlers.

Comment: Are you using any client mv* frameworks? You could, for example, put them in a Backbone view events object.

Comment: I believe knockout should be part of your question and tags to get  more effective answers. In a regular webpage, all you need is attaching events inside the DOM ready. In a page with dynamic content, you use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté thank you for that.  Now I need to do a bunch of research on event delegation :).  From what I have read so far, it only applies to dynamically bound elements (ie. Tables, and Lists), I suppose that this would also apply to dynamically generated popups?

Comment: @mcottingham Popups as in new windows/tabs? Unfortunately no as those would have different window objects.

Comment: Sorry, no, not popups.  I meant to say JQuery dialogs.